# In exchange for forbidding strikes, did Napoleon guarantee high wages?

Tags: economy, napoleon, labour-history

According to Wikipedia citing *Frank McLynn, Napoleon, Pimlico 1998 Ch 21, p482*, **strikes** were forbidden by Napoleon I **in exchange** for a guarantee by employers that wages would remain high.

How did this guarantee work?
Did Napoleon actually manage to ensure that wages remained high?
Did he at least act towards that goal?

Comment: I imagine his wars caused a labor shortage which raised wages.

Comment: Define "high"..

Comment: Higher than before

Comment: I can't see anything on the referenced page which states that Napoleon required a guarantee from employeers that workers wages would remain high. It merely says that "[Napoleon's] police sometimes prevented employers from lowering wages as part of a carefully calculated balancing act". Also, as noted in an earlier comment, "conscription produced a shortage of workers and forced wage rates up".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The referenced page which states that Napoleon required a guarantee from employers that workers wages would remain high. It merely says that "[Napoleon's] police sometimes prevented employers from lowering wages as part of a carefully calculated balancing act".

Also, it can be imagined that wars caused a labor shortage which raised wages.

*(based entirely on comments from Clint and Steve)*